# Modifying a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

Using just JavaScript and not a library such as jQuery, is there a more elegant way (such as `jquery.extend()`) to modify an object before passing it to a function?

```
var o={
    a:1,
    b:2,
    c:3,
    d:function(){alert('f');}
};
o.e='abc';
o.f='cba';
o.g=function(){alert ('f1');};
foo(o);
o.e='xyz';
o.f='zyx';
o.g=function(){alert ('f2');};
foo(o);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers other than any version of Internet Explorer (according to MDN anyway) support `Object.assign()`, which is more or less the same as `jQuery.extend()` other than its one-argument semantics.

```
foo(Object.assign(o, { e: "abc", f: "cba" }));
```

Should be available in Node too (again, ES2015 versions).

Comment: Thanks Pointy.  That was exactly what I was looking and hoping for, however, not being supported by any version of IE poses some problems.

Comment: There's what appears to be a decent polyfill [on the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: Works on IE Edge.  https://jsfiddle.net/813f1j24/.  Interestingly, console.log in Firebug shows the same values.  Actually, Firefox works, but firebug displays the wrong values.  https://jsfiddle.net/813f1j24/1/

Comment: @torazaburo if you call `jQuery.extend({foo: "hi"})` you're extending the jQuery prototype. So it's like `$.extend($.fn, {foo: "hi"});`

Comment: at least I think that's true; it might be `$` - I'll check. *edit* grr, jQuery docs are vague, and refer to "the jQuery namespace".

Comment: @torazaburo no sorry, it's the jQuery object itself that's the default target. (Which is a little goofy but whatever.) Personally I never use that feature and I only know it's there as part of remembering to avoid it :)

Comment: "Goofy" is being far too generous.